# Why does systemctl asks for a sudo password in user mode?

Tags: systemd, sudo, ssh-agent, systemd-user

I am currently trying to start my `ssh-agent` every time I login by starting it as a user service with systemd [as explained in the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Start_ssh-agent_with_systemd_user).

However, when I execute `systemctl --user start ssh-agent`, then `systemctl` prompts me for my password via sudo as if I were starting a usual service. It then fails because it isn't able to connect to the bus. Howvever, `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is `unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` and should be fine. But if I switch to the root user via `sudo su`, then `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is empty.
Therefore, I assume that the actual issue is that `systemctl` is trying to start the user service as root user instead of my user which is also why it prompts me for my password via sudo. So, I think that this is the actual issue.

So, does anybody know why `systemctl` executes via sudo as root even though I supplied `--user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there was an alias for `systemctl` that replaced it with `sudo systemctl` in `~/.bashrc.aliase`. That made it impossible to run `systemctl --user` properly.